# collect samaccount powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of users in a CSV, but I need to collect the SamAccount attribute from each user by name in the ad.

CSV model

[image]

Script

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "user" -and userAccountControl -eq "512"' -Properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName,CN,DisplayName, | Export-CSV -Path C:\Temp\UserAccounts.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm a little lost I don't know how to do a foreach using name

I am trying but without success.

Trying to get samaccountname based on Name on csv file.

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\userteste.csv | foreach-Object {Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $_.name} -Properties Name | Select-Object samAccountName}
```

and export to csv file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use `Get-ADObject` and not `Get-ADUser` for this? The latter gives you more of the desired properties you need in the CSV.

As aside, it is wasteful to do `-Properties *` if all you want is a small set of user attributes.

Something like this should work:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq $true" -Properties DisplayName, CN | 
    Select-Object SamAccountName, CN, DisplayName | 
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\UserAccounts.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

---

As per your comment you need to get some extra attributes of the users listed in the CSV, you can do this:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\userteste.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$($_.Name)'" -Properties DisplayName, CN | 
    Select-Object SamAccountName, CN, DisplayName
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\UserAccounts.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Theo, but i need like this: Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\userteste.csv | foreach-Object {Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $_.name} -Properties Name | Select-Object samAccountName} , based on csv file with Name, i need get samAccount of this Names. and export to csv this SamAccountName.

Comment: Not work, but i trying to do this based on you script.

Comment: @TássioCarlini Looking at the screenshot, you need to tell Excel to use UTF-8, because now it doesn't understand the ByteOrderMark. I would advise you to add switch `-UseCulture` to the `Export-Csv` command. The csv contains the data (open with notepad to check). It is Excel that doesn't understand the encoding when you doubleclick the file. `UseCulture` should fix that.